# subtract in time.localtime()

Tags: python

```
pol = True
if GPIO.input(inPut) == 1:
   while pol == True:
      start_time = time.localtime()
      start_time_format = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S:", start_time)
      pol == False
else:
   pol == True
current_time = time.localtime()
current_time_format = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S:", current_time)
work_time = current_time_format - start_time_format
print work_time
```

when i run it i got this error

```
     work_time = current_time_format - start_time_format
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

how can i subtract `current_time_format` from `start_time_format` ?
any correction for this ?
thanks in advance

Comment: so what would be the value of start_time if `GPIO.input(inPut) == 1` is false ?

Comment: there is no value for start_time if inPut == False because i want just calculate if inPut equal one

Comment: In that case, you should move the calculation to inside if, else it will again error out as you cannot subtract something from a variable that is not defined.

Comment: okey, your talk is true i will try to do that inside IF, if you had method provide me

Comment: you need to calculate the difference first before converting time into string with `strftime()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subtract dates with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4863994/how-to-subtract-dates-with-python)

Comment: similar my issue , i solved my problem by import ast , thank you for response

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

The main issue with your code is that you are trying to substract a variable that it is of type string from another one which is of type string too, and this is not possible *(at least in this manner)* because the class doesn't support this kind of operand

```py
work_time = current_time_format - start_time_format
```

and so you get the error below:

```
work_time = current_time_format - start_time_format
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

#### Solution:

Althought I don't know what your overall code is or what you really want to achive with it *(apart from getting the `work_time`)*, one way of doing this could be by using `deltatime` instead of `time`, like this:

```py
from datetime import datetime

# ...

pol = True
if GPIO.input(inPut) == 1:
   while pol == True:
      start_time = datetime.now() 
      pol == False
else:
   pol == True

current_time = datetime.now()
work_time = (current_time - start_time) # or 
# work_time = datetime.fromtimestamp((current_time - start_time).seconds).strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print work_time
```

#### References:

- *[Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28242294/11465149)*
- *[Subtract one strftime string from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074460/)*
- *[Time difference in milliseconds not working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426882/)*

Comment: long live your hand for this post

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all responses i solved my issue by this method :-

```
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import ast
...
pol = True
if GPIO.input(inPut) == 1:
    while pol == True:
      start_time = time.localtime()
      global houre
      houre = time.strftime("%H", start_time)
      global  minute
      minute = time.strftime("%M", start_time)
      global second
      second = time.strftime("%S", start_time)
      #time.sleep(5)
      pol = False
else:
    pol = True
current_time = time.localtime()
c_houre = time.strftime("%H", current_time)
c_minute = time.strftime("%M",current_time)
c_second = time.strftime("%S", current_time)

w_houre = ast.literal_eval(c_houre) - ast.literal_eval(houre)
w_minute = ast.literal_eval(c_minute) - ast.literal_eval(minute)
w_second = ast.literal_eval(c_second) - ast.literal_eval(second)

print(w_houre,":",w_minute,":",w_second)
```

maybe not true method but work for me, thanks for all